# JQuery: second .html() call ignores previous .css(), delay() & fadeIn() calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

## Warning: Newbe question. :-)

Using Ajax, I'm sending form data to an MVC3 controller and getting Json back.

On Success, I'm trying to:

1. Store the original form `div` contents (calling `.html()`)
2. Replace the html in the form `div` with the Json result (which is a string - "Success")
3. Delay for 3 seconds
4. Replace the html in the form `div` with the original html
5. Fade in the original form

It all works.  However, when the Success html displays, it immediately gets blown away by the second `.html()` call that puts the original form html back in the form div.  The `.delay(3000)` and `.css('display','none')` calls in between are seemingly ignored.

Proof: If I comment out the following lines of code (from the source below), the Success message is displayed.

```
$('#frmSignup').css('display', 'none');
$('#frmSignup').html(original).fadeIn();
```

I looked for similar cases and workarounds, but could not find any.  Please don't beat me that hard if this is obvious. ;-)

Thank you in advance for your assist!

## Source section:

$('form').live("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

```
var form = $(this);
var original = $('#frmSignup').html();

$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#goarrow').fadeOut();
        $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut();
        $('#goarrow').fadeIn();
        //$('#Email').val("");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data[0]) {
            $('#frmSignup').css('display', 'none');
            $('#frmSignup').html(data[1]).fadeIn().delay(3000);
            $('#frmSignup').css('display', 'none');
            $('#frmSignup').html(original).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#ajaxresponse").html(data[1]);
            //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: Did you try chaining everything? All examples for `delay` on jq site use chaining. something like `$('#frmSignup').html(data[1]).fadeIn().delay(3000).html(original).fadeIn();`

Comment: Hi bfavaretto.  Yes, I tried chaining and got the same result.  I broke the calls up to make it easy to comment out sections for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ton of experience with using .delay() but you could just use setTimeout

```
$('#frmSignup').css('display', 'none');
$('#frmSignup').html(data[1]).fadeIn();
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#frmSignup').css('display', 'none');
    $('#frmSignup').html(original).fadeIn();
},3000);
```

Or try chaining the elements when you use delay as per the jQuery docs.

also, instead of using .css('display', 'none'), you can use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It worked like a charm across all browsers.